# Query JSON Key:Value Pairs in AWS Athena

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-athena

I have received a data set from a client that is loaded in AWS S3. The data contains unnamed JSON key:value pairs. This isn't my area of expertise, so I was looking for a little help.

The structure of JSON data that I've typically worked with in the past looks similar to this:

`{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }`

The data that I have received from my client is formatted as such:

```
{
  "answer_id": "cc006",
  "answer": {
    "101086": 1,
    "101087": 2,
    "101089": 2,
    "101090": 7,
    "101091": 5,
    "101092": 3,
    "101125": 2
  }
}
```

This is survey data, where the key on the left is a numeric customer identifier, and the value on the right is their response to a survey question, i.e. customer "101125" answered the survey with a value of "2". I need to be able to query the JSON data using Athena such that my result set looks similar to:

[image]

Cross joining the unnested children against the parent node isn't an issue. What I can't figure out is how to select all of the keys from the array "answer" without specifying that actual key name. Similarly, I want to be able to select all of the values as well.

Is it possible to create a virtual table in Athena that would allow for these results, or do I need to convert the JSON to a format this looks more similar to the following:

```
{
  "answer_id": "cc006",
  "answer": [
    { "key": "101086", "value": 1 },
    { "key": "101087", "value": 2 },
    { "key": "101089", "value": 2 },
    { "key": "101090", "value": 7 },
    { "key": "101091", "value": 5 },
    { "key": "101092", "value": 3 },
    { "key": "101125", "value": 2 }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT 6/4/2020**

I was able to use the code that Theon provided below along with the following table structure:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE answer_example (
  answer_id string,
  answer string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/'
```

That allowed me to use the following query to generate the results that I needed.

```
WITH Data AS(
SELECT 
  answer_id, 
  CAST(json_extract(answer, '$') AS MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR)) as answer
FROM
  answer_example
)
SELECT 
  answer_id,
  key,
  element_at(answer, key) AS value
FROM 
  Data
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (map_keys(answer)) AS answer (key)
```

**EDIT 6/5/2020**

Taking additional advice from Theon's response below, the following DDL and Query simplify this quite a bit.

DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE answer_example (
  answer_id string,
  answer map<string,string>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/'
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  answer_id,
  key,
  element_at(answer, key) AS value
FROM 
  answer_example
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (map_keys(answer)) AS answer (key)
```

Comment: { "headers": [{ "key": "Name", "value": "xxxx" }, { "key": "Email", "value": "xxxx" }, { "key": "ID", "value": "1234" }, { "key": "Company", "value": "XYZ" }, { "key": "Groups", "value": "[]" }, { "key": "Address", "value": "xxxx" }, { "key": "State", "value": "Log In" }, { "key": "Component", "value": "xxxx" }, { "key": "LastUsed", "value": "xxxx" }] } My JSON looks like this I tried to use the DDL above to create the headers as map<string,string> data type but that doesnt parse the key value pairs, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross joining with the keys of the `answer` property and then picking the corresponding value. Something like this:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    'cc006' AS answer_id,
    MAP(
      ARRAY['101086', '101087', '101089', '101090', '101091', '101092', '101125'],
      ARRAY[1, 2, 2, 7, 5, 3, 2]
    ) AS answers
)
SELECT
  answer_id,
  key,
  element_at(answers, key) AS value
FROM data
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (map_keys(answers)) AS answer (key)
```

You could probably do something with `transform_keys` to create rows of the key value pairs, but the SQL above does the trick.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I'm looking for. My only other question would be how to replace the CTE (or WITH statement) with DDL for a virtual table that would accomplish the same results. Do I store the raw JSON in string format and use the json_extract function at the time of querying to simulate the array you have in the CTE? Or is there another way to go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to get it the rest of the way there. I modified my question above with the table structure and query. Thanks again!!

Comment: @rhholt great that you added the DDL, it always help when trying to understand the question. I used a CTE mostly to make the SQL self-contained. I think you would be fine typing your `answers` column as `map<string,string>` and skip the cast in the query, and you can skip the CTE, just select straight from `answer_example`.

Comment: When I try and remove the JSON cast in the CTE, I get an error "Cannot cast varchar to map(varchar,varchar)". I may not fully undestand what you meant by "typing your answers column as map<string, string>". If it's possible to simplify this, that would be great. My apologies, I've only been using Athena for a few days now, so this is all new to me.

Comment: I meant that you can create your table with `create table … (answer_id string, answers map<string,string>) …`

Comment: Well then... that was a lot easier :P I'll edit the DDL above. Thanks again for all of your help!